# Error executing action install on resource package[nginx]

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, cookbook

I am trying to install nginx on ec2 server using yum cookbook as dependancy.

This is what my nginx/recipe/default.rb looks like,

```
include_recipe "yum"

package "nginx" do 
version "1.6.2" 
action :install 
end

template "nginx.conf" do 
source "nginx.conf.erb" 
path "#{node['nginx']['dir']}/nginx.conf" 
action :create 
mode 0644 
end

template "default.conf" do 
source "default-site.erb" 
path "#{node['nginx']['dir']}/conf.d/default.conf" 
action :create 
mode 0644 
end

service "nginx" do 
supports :restart => :true 
action [:enable, :start] 
end
```

Also ,I have added the below line in metadata.rb

```
depends "yum"
```

On trying to run the below command on client ec2 server,

```
sudo chef-client
```

I get the following error:

```
[2014-12-15T01:38:31-05:00] WARN: 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
SSL validation of HTTPS requests is disabled. HTTPS connections are still
encrypted, but chef is not able to detect forged replies or man in the middle
attacks.
```

To fix this issue add an entry like this to your configuration file:

```
  # Verify all HTTPS connections (recommended)
  ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer

  # OR, Verify only connections to chef-server
  verify_api_cert true
```

To check your SSL configuration, or troubleshoot errors, you can use the

`knife ssl check` command like so:

```
knife ssl check -c /etc/chef/client.rb


* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

Starting Chef Client, version 11.16.4
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["yum", "nginx"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - yum
  - nginx
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 5 resources
Recipe: yum::default
  * yum_globalconfig[/etc/yum.conf] action create
    * template[/etc/yum.conf] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
Recipe: nginx::default
  * package[nginx] action install

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[nginx]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
    STDOUT: [option installonlypkgs] kernel kernel-bigmem installonlypkg(kernel-module) installonlypkg(vm) kernel-enterprise kernel-smp kernel-debug kernel-unsupported kernel-source kernel-devel kernel-PAE kernel-PAE-debug
    STDERR: yum-dump Repository Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
    https://rhui2-cds01.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7.0-1.el7/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
    https://rhui2-cds02.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7.0-1.el7/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
    ---- End output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
    Ran /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 returned 1

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/default.rb

     13: package "nginx" do
     14:   version "1.6.2"
     15:   action :install
     16: end
     17: 

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/default.rb:13:in `from_file'

    package("nginx") do
      action [:install]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      guard_interpreter :default
      package_name "nginx"
      version "1.6.2"
      timeout 900
      cookbook_name "nginx"
      recipe_name "default"
    end


Running handlers:
[2014-12-15T01:38:33-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2014-12-15T01:38:33-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-12-15T01:38:33-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 2.604475896 seconds
[2014-12-15T01:38:33-05:00] ERROR: package[nginx] (nginx::default line 13) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
STDOUT: [option installonlypkgs] kernel kernel-bigmem installonlypkg(kernel-module) installonlypkg(vm) kernel-enterprise kernel-smp kernel-debug kernel-unsupported kernel-source kernel-devel kernel-PAE kernel-PAE-debug
STDERR: yum-dump Repository Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://rhui2-cds01.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7.0-1.el7/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
https://rhui2-cds02.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7.0-1.el7/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
---- End output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
Ran /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 returned 1
[2014-12-15T01:38:33-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: would you mind formatting your text a bit to make it readable?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using the community nginx cookbook?  It does a pretty solid job.

Comment: @TejayCardon I am looking to configure my own test recipe without the much complex configurations listed in community nginx cookbook. I just want two template files to be created as of now.

Comment: @StephenKing Yes, I would love to sir, Can you please highlight which section is unclear to you?

Comment: Thanks @coderanger for [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27479279/revisions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this lines:

```
STDERR: yum-dump Repository Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
    https://rhui2-cds01.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7.0-1.el7/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
    https://rhui2-cds02.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7.0-1.el7/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

Yum have a problem reaching the repository. Seems like the yum config is wrong. 
You may test with a simple `yum install nginx` to see if its really a problem linked to chef (and in this case update the question) or if its only your system not properly registered/configured with rhn.

Comment: I tried 'Yum install nginx', looks like a problem with RHN,  [link]https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=555232